# Tinkerpop Gremlin Expression

Tags: graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

[image: Graph Structure]

In the above graph, I have users, Clients, Sites and Jobs. User is connected to Client (manages) and client (have) --> Sites (have) ---> Jobs. I'm trying to get all clients which have active jobs.

```
g.V().hasLabel('user').
      has('id', '338d219c-3457-4ad8-8172-37a7d897c0df').
      outE('manages').
      inV().
      hasLabel('client').
      outE('have').
      inV().
      hasLabel('site').
      outE('have').
      inV().
      hasLabel('job').
      has('status', 'In Progress')
```

The above query gets all jobs, but I'm interested in knowing Client, Site and Job. I was wondering how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few ways that you might do this, but first let's simplify your existing Gremlin since you say it does what you want:

```
g.V().has('user','id','338d219c-3457-4ad8-8172-37a7d897c0df').
  out('manages').
  hasLabel('client').
  out('have').
  hasLabel('site').
  out('have').
  has('job','status', 'In Progress')
```

Note that `outE().inV()` combinations like that are essentially just `out()`. In fact, if you write them as `outE().inV()` Gremlin will go through the trouble of re-writing the traversal to just `out()` when strategies are applied. See the `explain()` of the following two traversals:

```
gremlin> g.V().outE().inV().outE().inV().explain()
==>Traversal Explanation
=============================================================================================================================================================
Original Traversal                 [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN)]

ConnectiveStrategy           [D]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN)]
MatchPredicateStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN)]
FilterRankingStrategy        [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN)]
InlineFilterStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN), VertexStep(OUT,edge), EdgeVertexStep(IN)]
IncidentToAdjacentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
AdjacentToIncidentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
RangeByIsCountStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
RepeatUnrollStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
PathRetractionStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
LazyBarrierStrategy          [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
TinkerGraphCountStrategy     [P]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
TinkerGraphStepStrategy      [P]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
ProfileStrategy              [F]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
StandardVerificationStrategy [V]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]

Final Traversal                    [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
gremlin> g.V().out().out().explain()
==>Traversal Explanation
=============================================================================================================================================================
Original Traversal                 [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]

ConnectiveStrategy           [D]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
MatchPredicateStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
FilterRankingStrategy        [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
InlineFilterStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
IncidentToAdjacentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
AdjacentToIncidentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
RangeByIsCountStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
RepeatUnrollStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
PathRetractionStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
LazyBarrierStrategy          [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
TinkerGraphCountStrategy     [P]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
TinkerGraphStepStrategy      [P]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
ProfileStrategy              [F]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
StandardVerificationStrategy [V]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]

Final Traversal                    [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500)]
```

See how the final lines are identical? The `IncidentToAdjacentStrategy` applies that change, so ultimately both traversals compile to the same thing.

In answer to your original question, if you need to have the client, site and the job then use `select()`:

```
g.V().has('user','id','338d219c-3457-4ad8-8172-37a7d897c0df').
  out('manages').
  hasLabel('client').as('c').
  out('have').
  hasLabel('site').as('s').
  out('have').
  has('job','status', 'In Progress').as('j').
  select('c','s','j')
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, as the query comes back empty. Running it without adding .out('') works.

Comment: I added some more details. Not sure why `out()` would be a problem for you. You might want to recheck your code a bit. As you can see in my updated answer the end traversal should look the same using either approach.